# Python Format String With a String Which Contains Single Backslash

Tags: python, python-3.x, clickhouse

I have a simple yet annoying problem. I need to  format a string with a string which contains a single quote. So let's say I have this string to be formatted;

```
string_to_be_formatted = "Hello, {ANOTHER_STRING}"
```

Then I have another string;

```
another_string = r"You\'re genius"
```

So in the end, I would like to have the string as;

```
formatted_string = "Hello, You\'re genius"
```

When I print the formatted_string variable, it prints as expected, however when I use it as a variable and format a query with it, it uses the representation of the string. So far I've tried;

- literal_eval which is throwing an exception because of the single backslash
- Format string with '!s' option, same result

Any help is appreciated.

Edit : I think this is most likely related to Python clickhouse_driver. Sorry about that, I will open an issue about it.

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using for the formatting, and the resulting string. Works for me with: `a = "Hello, {X}"; b = "foo\'bar"; print(a.format(X=b))`

Comment: this works for me `string_to_be_formatted.format(ANOTHER_STRING=another_string)`

Comment: why do you even escape a single ' inside a "delimited string? It is not needed...

Answer (score 0):

You used a raw string to define your data. This means that the final string will still contain the backslash. If this was an error the solution is easy.

```
>>> template = "Hello, {data}"
>>> value = "You\'re genius"
>>> template.format(data=value)
"Hello, You're genius"
```

If you really have a string with an backslash and a single quote you can use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) but you have to take into account that you'll have to add quotes at the end and beginning.

```
>>> template = "Hello, {data}"
>>> value = r"You\'re genius"  # the same as value = "You\\'re genius"
>>> template.format(data=ast.literal_eval(f'"{value}"'))
"Hello, You're genius"
```

If you're on an older Python version without f-strings you can write

```
>>> template.format(data=ast.literal_eval('"' + value + '"'))
```

Answer (score -1):

It needs to use parameterized queries:

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client

client = Client(host='localhost')

another_string = r"You\'re genius"
string_to_be_formatted = f'''Hello, {another_string}'''


client.execute('INSERT INTO test (str) VALUES (%(str)s)', params={'str': string_to_be_formatted})
# SELECT *
# FROM test
#
# ┌─str───────────────────┐
# │ Hello, You\'re genius │
# └───────────────────────┘
#
# 1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.

print(client.execute("SELECT %(str)s", params={'str': string_to_be_formatted}))
# [("Hello, You\\'re genius",)]
```